# Removing the currency sign in formatCurrency() in thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf, currency

With this

```
 th:text="*{#numbers.formatCurrency(roomEntityList.get(0).price)}"
```

my browser will show `235.235 đ` in my country.
I want it to show `235.235` instead.

How can i remove the sign 'đ'?
I have already look it up but it seem theres not much we can do with formatCurrency in html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any native support for this in the documentation, but one way you can accomplish it is with regular expressions:

```html
<span
  th:with="originalPrice=${#numbers.formatCurrency(roomEntityList.get(0).price)}, 
           onlyNumbersAndDot=${#strings.replaceAll(originalPrice, '[^\\d.]+', '')}" 
  th:utext="${onlyNumbersAndDot}"
></span>
```

First, `th:with` is used to create two variables:

- `originalPrice` holds the formatted currency value
- `onlyNumbersAndDot` applies the regular expression `[^\\d.]+` to `originalPrice`, which matches any unwanted characters so `replaceAll` can replace them with an empty string

Then `th:utext` is then used to display the modified price, which now contains only numbers and dots.